# java проблема с stax

Tags: java, xml, парсер

При парсинге xml staxom возникают ошибки, я так понял что основная ошибка

```
at StaxRun.parseXML(StaxRun.java:32)
```

джава почему то не может найти xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class StaxRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException {
        String fileName = "D:/work/java/Xml/src/products.xml";
        try {
            List<Product> list = parseXML(fileName);
            for (Product elem : list) {
                System.out.println(elem);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Product> parseXML(String fileName) throws XMLStreamException, ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        List<Product> list = null;
        Product curProduct = null;
        String tagContent = null;
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileName));
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            int event = reader.next();
            switch (event) {
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                if ("product".equals(reader.getLocalName())) {
                    curProduct = new Product();
                }
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                tagContent = reader.getText().trim();
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:

                switch (reader.getLocalName()) {
                case "product":
                    list.add(curProduct);
                case "name":
                    curProduct.setName(tagContent);
                case "mod":
                    curProduct.setModel(tagContent);
                case "manufacturer":
                    curProduct.setManufacturer(tagContent);
                case "color":
                    curProduct.setColor(tagContent);
                case "date":
                    curProduct.setDate(format.parse(tagContent));
                case "price":
                    curProduct.setPrice(Double.valueOf(tagContent));
                case "count":
                    curProduct.setCount(Integer.valueOf(tagContent));
                    break;

                }

                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                break;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

класс product

```
    import java.util.Date;

public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private Date date;
    private String color;
    private double price;
    private int count;
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name+price;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price=price;
    }

}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///D:/epam/epamXML/products-schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<product id="1">
<name>стол</name>
<mod>аа111</mod>
<manufacturer>мебельный комбинат</manufacturer>
<color>дуб</color>
<date>10.01.2010</date>
<price>4500</price>
<count>3</count>
</product>
<product id="2">
<name>стул</name>
<mod>бб111</mod>
<manufacturer>мебельный комбинат</manufacturer>
<color>дуб</color>
<date>10.01.2010</date>
<price>1500</price>
<count>10</count>
</product>
<product id="3">
<name>люстра</name>
<mod>дд222</mod>
<manufacturer>ооо новое стекло</manufacturer>
<color>прозрачный</color>
<date>22.01.2016</date>
<price>1000</price>
<count>7</count>
</product>
<product id="4">
<name>шкаф купе</name>
<mod>бг001</mod>
<manufacturer>мебельный комбинат</manufacturer>
<color>комбинированный</color>
<date>10.03.2016</date>
<price>15000</price>
<count>1</count>
</product>
<product id="5">
<name>плафон</name>
<mod>дш091</mod>
<manufacturer>ооо новое стекло</manufacturer>
<color>прозрачный</color>
<date>05.08.2001</date>
<price>350</price>
<count>43</count>
</product>
</products>
```

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileName)` может вернуть `null`, если файл не в classpath, проверьте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

меняется на

```
XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```